# How do I ensure my online Adventure League character(s) stay legal?

Tags: dnd-5e, online-roleplaying, dnd-adventurers-league

I am currently playing in the DDAL05 (Dungeons and Dragons Adventure League Season 5 I believe) that takes place along side the Storm King's Thunder hard cover adventure.  This is my first foray into Adventure League play and I find there are quite a few rules to ensuring fair play down the board and to make sure these characters can be taken to events and Conventions and used without too much trouble.

My question is, considering this is hosted over a Virtual Tabletop and not a physical one, how do I ensure this character can be used elsewhere in future Adventure League Modules and Adventures if I wanted to take it with me to a convention or my local game store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Adventurer's League Player's Guide is your one stop shop for this. It is meant to be both the document that defines what is and isn't legal for AL play, as well as the reference guide to the same. It is freely available online, and as far as I'm aware it always will be.

The guide is updated for every season of AL play, so as long as you have the most recent version your character will be legal. The current (Storm King's Thunder) version is [here](http://www.dmsguild.com/m/product/190680), but for anyone reading this in the future, be aware that this link might be out of date.

Comment: I realize the information for *making* an AL character can be found in the supporting online documents, and I have downloaded them all from the Faction Guide to the AL Players and DM Guides.  My question is, if I wanted to take this character from a Virtual Table top to a real Tabletop , what do I need?  We don't have an Adventure League Log Sheet, for instance.  The integrated character sheet handles those kind of things.

Comment: @Airatome That's on the first page of the Player's Guide - you need a logsheet. Technically, if you've been playing without one, your character hasn't been playing AL, and if you try to bring it to an AL game, it would be considered a pregenerated character with level >1, so not AL legal.

Comment: You will need to have a completed log sheet with your character if you are planning on taking it outside of the current game you are playing. Your online DM may not be tracking this for you, so that would be an activity you need to complete.